# OpenStreetMap: How to display borders of districts in a country?

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to display district borders of a country plus the main city of the district. Later, I want do colour the area based on some values calculated by my application (native C++).

Because of the minimum budged for the task, I may want to use OpenStreetMap. But I am very new to geo things, and there is a lot of new things to learn. I need some hints where to start.

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to edit the corresponding map with one of the many tools that openstreetmap provides.

Have a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

and here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editing .

There are both an online editor that you can use while looking at a map on the openstreetmap (Potlach: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Potlatch_2 ) web and a few desktop based tools, like Merkaartor:

http://merkaartor.be/

A complete list is here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Comparison_of_editors

Just be sure you are adding meaningful, copyright-free data to the map because it will be the same map that everybody will use (worldwide!).

Should you need a private version of openstreetmap (that is: a map visible just to your users), you will have to host your own tile/map server. This requires hardware, software, skills and time.

In any case, see the forum and the mailing list of openstreetmap and have some talk with the people there. You will get all of the info you need for your project.

Should you need to build a map viewer or something like that, have a look at QuantumGIS (a C++ and Qt-based map viewer and editor) and to the desktop-based programs created by the openstreetmap community. Most likely, you can find something ready for the use. At least, you will find some code to be used as a starting point or as a working example. QGIS is here:

http://www.qgis.org/